# ¿Cómo asignar valores a multiples variables introducidas por teclado?

Tags: python

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    a,b,c,d=line.split(" ")
    e=(a+b+c+d)/6
    print(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Quiero que `a`, `b`, `c` y `d` sean enteros o float para poder operar en `e` , puedo poner float(a), float(b), etc... pero es muy trabajoso, hay alguna forma de declarar la variable como float, entero o lo que sea?

Trato de hacer:

```
 float(a), float(b), float(b), float,(d)=line.split(" ")
 a, b, c, d = float(line.split(" ")
```

Lo cual no es correcto.
Haciendo de la siguiente forma  no tengo problemas.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    e = 0.0
    for res in line.split(" "):
        e = float(res) + e
        print(e)
```

Pero me parecen muchas líneas para poder capturar solo unos numeros.

¿Qué método puedo usar para poder capturar los datos?

En C lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
float a, b, c, d;
scanf("%f%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea donde asignas los valores podrías usar una *comprehension* o puedes usar `map`. Por ejemplo, con `map` sería:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    a, b, c, d = map(float, line.split(" "))
    e = (a + b + c + d) / 6
    print(a, b, c, d, e)
```